# File Upload Fails Despite Meeting Configuration Criteria PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to let the user upload a file using CodeIgniter's built-in file upload class.

This is the upload form:

**upload_form.php**

```
<?php if($error) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <p><?php echo $error;?></p>
</div>
<?php endif ;?>

<form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?=base_url().'upload/do_upload'?>" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userfile" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Picture</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="file" id="userfile" name ="userfile">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="col-sm-offset-1 btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, the user chooses a file, then submits it.

This is the form's action file:

**upload.php**

```
        //Checks Image Before Upload, Throws Errors Or Uploads, Resizes And Shows Upload Success Page
    function do_upload()

    {
        //Config Parameters For Allowed Uploads
        $config['upload_path']= base_url().'uploads';
        $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpeg|png|jpg|bmp';
        $config['max_size']='5000';
        $config['max_width']='10000';
        $config['max_height']='10000';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; 
        

        //Load The Upload Library With Said Configuration
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        
        //If The Image Didn't Meet The Required Parameters
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload())

            {
                //Throw An Error, Then Load The Uplaod Form Again With The Error Deatils
                $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('upload_form',$error);
                $this->load->view('footer');
                echo "here";
                die();
            }

        //If The Image Met The Required Parameters
        else

            {
                                 Upload Image
            }
        
        }
```

Please take note that:

1. The form's `action` leads to the correct place.
2. The form's `enctype` is correctly set to `multipart/form-data`/
3. I adhere to the exact requirements at [CI's Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Given all these, the `do_upload` function still fails to execute (meaning - `(!$this->upload->do_upload())` is true) and the error that is logged to the error array (via codeigniter's `display_errors()` function) is **You did not select a file to upload.**

Dicing the question up to digestable chunks:

1. Why is the function failing to begin with?
2. Why is this error displayed, when I clearly tried to upload a file?
3. Which is the fault in all this -  a crudely-written form, or a misuse of CI's File Upload Class?

Comment: try config ['upload_path']= './uploads'

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got The solution eventually - somethhing to do with the `<form>` tag setup.

This is the correct one:

```
<form action="upload_destination_url" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the mimes type issue.
Please check the mime type is available in the mimes configuration file mimes.php

If not then get mime type by following code

```
echo $this->upload->file_type ; // will give mime type of file.
```

Use it after

```
$this->upload->do_upload();
```

You will get the mime type. Add that mime type in the file mimes.php  located in

/application/config

Like e.g. if the file has extension pptx and mime type is application/powerpoint
then update the $mimes array for pptx as

```
 'pptx' => array('application/powerpoint')
```

**EDIT :**

Done following changes and it works for me.

1) In view I have added `method="post"`

`<form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url().'welcome/do_upload'?>" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >`

2) And in contoller upload path declared as

```
$config['upload_path']= './uploads/';
```

This uploads directory is in same folder as application directory is.

Comment: It fails on `$this->upload->do_upload(); `, How am i suppose to put anything after it?

Comment: Yes the uploading fails. But still you will get the mime type. Please refer http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/09/codeigniter-file-upload-and-mime-types/

Comment: Hey Tom. I have done two small changes it is working for me. 1) In view file specified the method as POST for submitting form and 2) in controller upload path declared as $config['upload_path']= './uploads/'; Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @piyush. However - as you can see, I've found the solution.